# Carbon frame damage

Tags: carbon

Please help. What should I do? I just bought a full carbon road bike that is less than 30 days old and noticed a hairline glitch where the seat post and seat stay meet that I can feel with my fingernail. It is about 3/4 of an inch long. Similar spots were found but turned out to be lines created by leftover warning sticker glue. It took a lot of simple green, white lightening to remove the glue. I have never had an accident or dropped her and cleaning has had no effect.

Comment: 30 days old? Why are you even here; this is a warranty claim.

Answer (score 6):

The best thing you can do is contact the LBS (local bike shop) or online shop where from you got the bike. They'll tell you what to do (most probably handle it with the distributor themselves or tell you to contact the distributor directly).

Take good photos of the issue and forward them to the ones you contact. Keep your purchase receipt handy for when requested.